# TFS 2010 and 2015 really slow when deleting branches

Tags: tfs, branch, tfs-2015

We develop every US and Bug on a branch to be able to review the code related with that element so we generate a nice amount of branches. Every month we delete the old ones and traditionally this process has been way too slow.

We can only commit the deletion of 6 to 10 branches at once, otherwise we get a timeout. The deletion of 10 branches takes more that 5 minutes.

We have migrated recently from TFS 2010 and VS 2010 to TFS 2015 and VS2015 and nothing changed.

Is this normal? Is there a way to speed up this? Looking for an answer in google all I found is something related with local workspaces which is not the case, the workspace is remote.

Regards.

Comment: How big is your branch , did the branch have a number of folders with a large number of files ?And did you give a try with deleting your branch one by one (after a delete then check in the pending changes)?

Comment: It sounds like your TFS server is under powered for your purpose. What is the spek?

Comment: All the normal operations run normally. The issue here is only deleting branches :\

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with workspaces. All workspace-related operations seem to be taking ages, and I believe the delete command is checking the status of the branch in all remote workspaces. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to skip the checks, so it is still taking a long time (about 10 minutes for 30 branches). If I ever get around to deleting unused workspaces and performance improves, I will post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

First, please check if other operations also delay so long, like adding a file, are fast.

And you could use [tf delete command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k45zb450(v=vs.100).aspx) instead of GUI in VS. Which may do the trick. Deleting the branch will only actually perform a "soft delete". The branch will still exist complete with all of it's history, except it will be hidden. If you want to **permanently deletes version-controlled files** from Team Foundation version control, need to perform a [tf destroy command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Also check if it's a client issue, like a conflicting Visual Studio add-in. Try to [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/).Besides, you could use another account and machine to do the delete operation next month.

Must to say there is some delay of deleting branch in TFS using VS GUI. I have created 20 empty branches for test. It took about 30 seconds to complete the whole delete operation. So if your branch  have a number of folders with a large number of files, then the deletion of 10 branches takes about 5 minutes looks like acceptable. After all in TFVC, we don't create and delete branches frequently like GIT.